# message length in python send() similar to send() in C

Tags: c, python-3.x, sockets, ssl, openssl

I'm trying to send data using sockets and ssl in python.  The server is written in C and so it expects to receive:

```
bytesRx = recv(socket, buffer, sizeof(buffer),0)
```

so in C the send function is:

```
send(socket, messsage, length, 0)
```

I want to mimic the send function but in python there is no option inside the send() function to send the length of the message.  Only the message itself is sent.

```
secure_socket.send(message)
```

is there a way to include the message length on the python send() function to make the server happy?

Comment: Do you have evidence that the server is unhappy?

Comment: 1) The `send` syscall does *NOT* send the length of the message, the length is only used because the kernel needs to know the length of the data to send. 2) The Python `send` method of sockets is a higher level version of the `send` syscall, and since python objects that can be sent through `send` already have a length (retrievable through `len()`), there is no need to specify it. - The Python function will do the appropriate `send` syscall under the hood adding the length for you. 3) "make the server happy" does not mean anything. If you have trouble, show the code.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

In Python, the message length is... the length of the message. Python strings have lengths and C strings don't. That's why you need to specify the message and length separately in C, but not in Python.

If you want to only send the first 100 bytes of the message, you can write:

```
secure_socket.send(message[:100])
```

In Python, `message[:100]` means the first 100 things in `message` - in this case, I assume `message` is a byte string, so it means the first 100 bytes.

Comment: *"Python messages have lengths and C messages don't"* - the concept of message does not exist in C nor in Python.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli I use the word "message" to make it obvious how the sentence relates to the code.